# Can someone explain how it's possible to get the Necromancer badge without answering any questions?

Tags: support, badges, deleted-answers

Was looking at a question posed by this user, noticed he had a low score but yet had a silver badge.  So, when I looked at his profile it said he had the Necromancer badge, yet stated he had answered 0 questions.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/1171203/napkinbob

Is this a glitch, or do answers go away somehow or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They were awarded it for an [answer that they later deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151034/psexec-gets-stuck-on-licence-prompt-when-running-non-interactively/11325297#11325297). The badge is not revoked as a result of the deletion.

Comment: Why would anyone delete an answer that they got a +5 score on?  The question couldn't have been deleted once it had an answer on it.  Just trying to reason that one out.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - Could be they figured they made a mistake the upvoters didn't catch. Could be they liked a competing answer better and thought theirs looked pale beside it and didn't deserve living any longer.

Comment: Gotcha.  OK, that makes sense.

Comment: @JohnnyBones - per one of the comments in the deleted answer:  `Giving you an upvote to help you get enough rep to make this a comment, which is what it should be :)`  Looks like it was from a new user who didn't have enough rep at the time, and people upvoted the answer enough to the point where the user deleted their answer and made it a comment.  And got the Disciplined badge while they were at it :)

Comment: @JohnnyBones It seems that people up voted the answer (at least in part) so that the user would have enough reputation to instead [post it as a comment on another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5151034/psexec-gets-stuck-on-licence-prompt-when-running-non-interactively/11325297#comment24078923_5151078).

Comment: My brain sort of exploded for a minute there, but now it all makes sense.